# searchable dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select, react-virtualized

I have below list in react.

```
<select
    id="sponsor" 
    name="sponsor"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Sponsor"
    }
    >
    <option value="" selected>Please select the sponsor</option>
     {
     active && result.map((sponsor:Sponsor,index:number)=>
          <option  value={sponsor.id} >{sponsor.name}</option>    
      )
    }

</select>
```

it is working perfectly fine. now I need to change it to searchable list. I did below.

```
     import VirtualizedSelect from 'react-virtualized-select'
    import "react-virtualized-select/styles.css";
    import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
     

 <VirtualizedSelect
        id="sponsor" 
        name="sponsor"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Sponsor"
        options={ active && result.map((sponsor:Sponsor,index:number)=>
            {sponsor.name}
          
        )}

     >
       </VirtualizedSelect>
```

now nothing is coming in list. basically my requirement is to make list searchable and insert data of API into that list.

Could you please help me with same? Any other option will also be very helpful

```
Edit1:-
```

I need list like below. first line "Please choose sponsor"

[image]

Comment: alert(result); wont print anything because setResultis asynchronous,
try printing the result like
useEffect(()=>{console.log(result)} , [result])

Comment: can you put a screenshot of error you are getting

Comment: Within the `return` and in `result.map`, instead of `{sts}`, please try with: `{sts.request_status}` and see if that helps.

Comment: You are already making use of a library `react-virtualized-select`. What does the documentation for that library say about creating a searchable list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to VirtualizedSelect docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized-select, the component accept array of objects like :

```
    const options = [
      { label: "One", value: 1 },
      { label: "Two", value: 2 },
      { label: "Three", value: 3, disabled: true }
      // And so on...
    ]
```

not array of strings and I think this is way its not working, I'd suggest to change your code to :

```
 <VirtualizedSelect
        id="sponsor" 
        name="sponsor"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Sponsor"
        options={ active && result.map((sponsor:Sponsor,index:number)=>
            ({label: sponsor.name, value: sponsor.name})
          
        )}

     >
       </VirtualizedSelect>
```

Comment: thank you Omar. that works incredibly well.can we also add "Please select sponsor" in the top ?

Comment: I have edited quetion and I need only little more help, please

Comment: hey Oma, I have put fresh question for it, if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426944/searchable-dropdown-list-in-react