# Not able to display drop down list in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My API is returning below result.

[image]

I have below code to display in list.

```
const [result,setResult] = useState([]);
const fetchStatus = async ()=>{
       await httpClient.get( config.resourceServerUrl+"/certificates/status").then(res=>{
       setResult(res.data);
        setActive(true);
        alert(result);
       })
```

and I am displaying list like below.

```
<div className="col-md-4">
                                <label htmlFor="status">Status</label>
                                <select
                                name="requestStatus"
                                style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                                <option value="" selected >
                                    Please Select the Status
                                </option>
                               {
                                  
                                 active &&  result.map((sts:any)=>{
                                       <option key="" value="">
                                           {sts}
                                       </option>
                                   })
                               }
                          </select>
```

though there is no error but it is not displaying anything.

[image]

Comment: Could you try replacing `{sts}` with `sts.request_status`?

Comment: Its not working. even I simply put {1} still its not working. there is no error but values are not getting populated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [value is not getting displayed in drop down list in API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336643/value-is-not-getting-displayed-in-drop-down-list-in-api-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't believe you await `httpClient.get`. The `.then` will be called when  the get completes.
2. you are setting the dropdown to each object in the returned array. You want to set it to the value of the `request_status` key: `sts.request_status`
3. set the `key` attribute for elements you create using `map`

   {
   active &&  result.map((sts:any)=>{

   {sts.request_status}

   })
   }

Comment: thank you @Dave . your solution is working. tell me one thing, is my API calling not appropriate? I mean I want to improve if it is not proper.

Comment: I believe you want to remove the `await` keyword if you're using .then(). Otherwise, you can say `const res = await httpClient.get()` and on the next few lines the contents of your then() method. I haven't used that call in a long time, so not positive - but it's very unlikely you'd want to mix async/await and then() apis.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you've got {} around your JSX, should be ()

```
active &&  result.map((sts:any) => ( 
  <option>{sts}</option> 
))
```

or you can do

```
active &&  result.map((sts:any) => {
   return (
     <option>{sts}</option> 
   )
})
```