# searchable dropdown list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-select

I have serchable dropdown list in react. for that I have used `VirtualizedSelect` the problem is onChange is not working.

```
import VirtualizedSelect from 'react-virtualized-select'
import "react-virtualized-select/styles.css";
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
<VirtualizedSelect
       id="sponsor" 
       name="sponsor"
       defaultValue="Please"
       className="form-control"
       placeholder="Sponsor"
       options=  { active && result.map((sponsor:Sponsor,index:number)=>
           ({label: sponsor.name, value: sponsor.name})
       
       )} 
       onChange={ (e:any)=>{printValue(e)}}
        }>
</VirtualizedSelect>
```

inside the `printValue` I am printing `alert(e.target.value`) and it is printing `undefined`.

```
const printValue=(e:any)=>{
    alert("value is"+e.target.value);
}
```

also as of now `list` is coming like below.

[image]

I want it to make like below. I mean I want to add "Please select the sponsor"
[image]

can you please help me on the same?
if I am printing `console.log(e.target.value)` inside the method. it is throwing below error.

[image]

Edit1:-
it is coming like below.

[image]

Comment: can you post the printValue function?

Comment: thank you. I have included on the question

Comment: also can you please help with label issue as well?

Comment: can you try  onChange={ (e:any)=>{console.log(e)}} and tell what the outcome is?

Comment: Also which package are you using for the Virtualized Select? They may have a different method of handling events.

Comment: its react-virtualized-select

Comment: Yeah you will need to use a different method.  Here's the link to the documentation on how to handle events: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select

Comment: Hi @SeanLawton can you help with label issue like if I want to add "Please select sponsor" in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could approach this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

import VirtualizedSelect from 'react-virtualized-select'

function App() {

  const options = [
    { label: "One", value: 1 },
    { label: "Two", value: 2 },
    { label: "Three", value: 3 },
    { label: "Four", value: 4 },
    { label: "Five", value: 5 },
    { label: "Six", value: 6 }
  ]

  const [item, setItem] = useState(null)

  return (
    <>
      <VirtualizedSelect
        options={options}
        onChange={(value) => setItem(value)}
        value={item}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Edit 1:

Import the default styles which are these lines in your component

```
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
import 'react-virtualized-select/styles.css'
```

Edit 2:
react-select v2 upwards don't provide the css file due to various reasons. One of the way is to add the css file manually by copy-pasting which I suggested.

Screenshot proof:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi @Harry  can you help with label issue like if I want to add "Please select sponsor" in list

Comment: You mean like a placeholder?

Comment: If you want please select sponsor as placeholder its incredibly easy

Comment: I have put image at the end in question.Could you please check the same? can I make it better?

Comment: I am confused, you want "Please select sponsor" as the item in list or just the placeholder?

Comment: placeholder...but please see in the top it is very small....check the box it is very tiny

Comment: Got it. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I have added image again..marked the same.

Comment: @ShrutiSharma I have edited my answer. Check now!

Comment: actually it used to work in old version of react-select. now it does not work .   it is giving error.  Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Comment: this is thread regarding same.  https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2594

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242824/discussion-between-harry-and-shruti-sharma).

Comment: is there anything we can do using CSS?

Comment: npm i react-select@1.2.1 and you will be good to go